# Removing few characters from factor in R

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I don't know how can I remove some part of factor in R. 
I have data like this :

```
District                       X
District - Purba Champaran    12
District - Purba Champaran    86
District - Purba Champaran    56
District - Sheohar            13 
District - Sheohar            45
District - Sheohar            13
```

I want to eliminate the "District -" part from each district names. 
Please also tell me, What if some district names  not include "District -" in their names then how it can be done?

Comment: Here, district is a factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have :

```
df<-structure(list(District = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("District - Purba Champaran", 
"District - Sheohar"), class = "factor"), X = c(12, 86, 56, 13, 
45, 13)), .Names = c("District", "X"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

We can use `sub` : `df[,1]<-sub('District - ','',df[,1])`

```
df
#          District  X
# 1 Purba Champaran 12
# 2 Purba Champaran 86
# 3 Purba Champaran 56
# 4         Sheohar 13
# 5         Sheohar 45
# 6         Sheohar 13
```

It will remove the "District - " from each row of `df` for the first column. If there is no "District - " in a row, it will do nothing.

Comment: thanks @etienne. I have no idea about this function.

Comment: @Neeraj: You're welcome. You can look at `?grep` for more info on those kind of functions.